# Web Method is not identified

Tags: asp.net, webforms, asp.net-ajax

Error Says
HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
(XHR)POST - http://localhost:57102/WebForm1.aspx/Details1

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="ABC.WebForm2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function GetData() {
            alert('Get Data Called');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'WebForm1.aspx/Details1',
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                cache: false,
                success: function (_data) {
                    alert('success call');
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert('error call');
                }
            });
        }

    </script>

    <input type="button" value="Get Details" onclick="GetData()" />

</body>
</html>
```

and Web Method is as follows

```
   [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string Details1()
    {
        return "Hellow";          
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `GET` instead of `POST`?

Comment: Yes Tried with GET as well

Comment: @KarthikDheeraj The file may be named WebForm1.aspx but looking at the `Page` directive I can see `WebForm2` all over the place...

Comment: Did you get this working?